# Reading and Writing data into a file printing invalid data

Tags: c, loops

The question says to write a program to read several sets of prices and discounts from a file choosing a end-of-data marker such as 0 or -1. 
It also says to print the original price, discounted amount and final price in another file (output) the customer must pay.

This is what i wrote in input.txt:

```
285 30
300 25
0
```

This is the source:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE * in = fopen("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\c\\price.txt","r");
    FILE * out = fopen("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\c\\priceout.txt","w");

    double price, discountedAmount, finalPrice;
    int disPercent;

    fscanf(in,"%lf",&price);

    while(price != 0) {
        fscanf(in,"%d",&disPercent);
        discountedAmount = price * disPercent / 100;
        finalPrice = price - discountedAmount;
        fscanf(in,"%lf",&price);

        fprintf(out,"The original price is: %.2f\n",price);
        fprintf(out,"The discount amount is: %.2f\n",discountedAmount);
        fprintf(out,"Final Price is: %.2f",finalPrice);
    }
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the what the program wrote into output.txt:

```
The original price is: 300.00
The discount amount is: 85.50
Final Price is: 199.50

The original price is: 0.00
The discount amount is: 75.00
Final Price is: 225.00
```

Shouldnt the program be stopping at 0? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You're using equality operators on a `double` (floating-point) value, which doesn't work the way you expect: `(price != 0)`.

Comment: @DanFego as much as what you say is true... in above example problem is printing at wrong places... the loop is terminating... (its not infinite loop)... so `!=0` check does work.. problem is that OP is reading the next value before printing original value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code... you are printing at wrong place thats what causing the problem..

you are first reading the next price and then going ahead... 
use below code..

```
fscanf(in,"%lf",&price);

while(price != 0) {
    fscanf(in,"%d",&disPercent);
    discountedAmount = price * disPercent / 100;
    finalPrice = price - discountedAmount;

    fprintf(out,"The original price is: %.2f\n",price);
    fprintf(out,"The discount amount is: %.2f\n",discountedAmount);
    fprintf(out,"Final Price is: %.2f",finalPrice);
    fscanf(in,"%lf",&price);  // THIS LINE is now after printing previous values..


}
```

Comment: This worked but left a little confused. When it read the 0 value why didnt the loop stopped?

Comment: @user2409559 after reading the 0 value loop did stop in your case.... in WHile loop... `condition` is evaluated if true then `whole loop contents` that is code in `{}` is executed (assuming no `break` or `continue`) ..then again... condition is evaluated.. in your case you read the price...print it and then code checks it for 0... so loop ends after printing 0...

Comment: Yes the main problem was actually reading 3 values from scanf then printing when it should have been only 2. one for orignal price and another for discount value then printing the value and finally scanning the next price. Thanks for your valuable help.

Answer (score 2):

`while(price != 0)` only checked at the beginning of each loop. not each time `price` has changed.

you can ommit the first read, and do:

```
while (1) {
    fscanf(in,"%lf",&price);
    if (price == 0) // comparing floating point is bad, but I think it's ok here.
        break;
    fscanf(in,"%d",&disPercent);
    discountedAmount = price * disPercent / 100;
    finalPrice = price - discountedAmount;

    fprintf(out,"The original price is: %.2lf\n",price);
    fprintf(out,"The discount amount is: %.2lf\n",discountedAmount);
    fprintf(out,"Final Price is: %.2lf",finalPrice);
}
```